# Rendering small polygons on high zoom using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I've noticed that GeoServer 2.7.6 has the capability to NOT render on high zoom small polygons. And GeoServer 2.11 is rendering all the features/polygons from a layer.
How can I make GeoServer 2.11 to stop rendering small polygons on high zoom?!
I've searched answers on Google but I didn't find info about this topic.
Only SLD scale dependent rule.

Comment: You are using PostGIS then check if "Support on the fly geometry simplification" is set on your PostGIS datastore settings. Maybe a reversed duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/small-features-dont-draw-when-zoomed-out-using-geoserver-wms/234035#234035

Comment: It's active. I have 2 VPS - one with Geoserver 2..7.6 and one with 2.11. Both have Geometry SImplifcation. But the data it's rendered different.

Comment: That's odd. Set the GeoServer logging level to GeoTools developer, do some browsing on the map and find from the logs the SQL statements which is sent to PostGIS. ST_Simplify should appear there when you have selected the on-the-fly simplification.

Comment: THey appear. Odder is that both Geoserver's are using same postgis database :)

Comment: That is really odd because same SQL must return same features from the database. The small polygons must come from PostGIS because GeoServer can't render them from nothing.

Comment: The polygons are rendered ok. Are renderd all. But what I want to say it's that Geoserver 2.7.6 is capable to hide small polygons at high zoom level. And Geoserver 2.11 isn't. Or I have a problem somewhere. I think the capability to hide polygons at high zoom is very useful for resources and rendering time/processing.

Comment: GeoServer does not hide the polygons. Is puts the load to PostGIS and reads the polygons from PostGIS by using ST_Simplify http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html which is reducing the number of vertices in big geometries and dropping out small geometries. Therefore if GS 2.7.6 and 2.11 are creating identical SQL the result should be the same. However, it appears that it is not. Perhaps developers have changed how SQL requests are built for some reason. I can imagine that in some other use cases totally missing polygons are bad. I would write to geoserver-users mailing list and ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your `datastore.xml` of Geoserver 2.11. If you are using the `datastore.xml` from the former version, it is possible that the **Support on the fly geometry simplification** is not present in the configuration file.

Make sure your `datastore.xml` contains:

```
  <connectionParameters>
    (...)
    <entry key="Support on the fly geometry simplification">true</entry>
    (...)
  </connectionParameters>
```

Comment: The entry ket exists and it's "true". Thanks