# Geoserver shape simplification performance

Tags: geoserver, performance, simplify

So, while wondering about shape simplification in the eternal struggle for optimization, I find out (here on SE) that Geoserver and PostGIS can and will (by default) perform the trick on the fly (see [Small features don't draw when zoomed out using Geoserver WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225003/small-features-dont-draw-when-zoomed-out-using-geoserver-wms)), all by themselves.

A number of questions come to mind (does it work with shapefiles too ? at which point of the process does it happen ? obviously the renderer must simplify the shape in any case, simply because of available pixels - but does a non-simplified shape that gets simplified on rendering have the same weight resource-wise as one that's pre-simplified ?), but to pick one:

how much of a resource hit is it, compared to preparing simplified versions of the geometries beforehand ?

The spider sense says it should be significant, but Geoserver has surprised me several times already in the brief time we have known each other.

Answer (score 1):

As you note this is a default option for PostGIS datastores where the work can be offloaded to the database. So it is not available by default for other stores.

But there is a [pre-generalized datastore](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/vector/featurepregen.html) that you can add to GeoServer which will do something similar using a collection of generalised shapefiles. There is a (pre-2.0) [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/feature-pregeneralized/feature-pregeneralized_tutorial.html) that may help you get started.

Comment: Not the actual question, but good job answering all the others in one go.

Comment: your actual question is pretty much impossible to answer for anything but a specific dataset and styling combo

Comment: I agree, and I should edit it as soon as I figure out a way to do it that makes sense in human. I am trying to figure it out in terms of negligible/unconcerning/significant/crippling, within the given terms of comparison. Of course, finding that that job is given to the database entirely already half knocks the question out, as it seems like a type of task the db would be comfortable with.

Comment: I suppose the bottom line is "should I bother in general ?".